# FindFirstChild cannot find first child and no code feedback

Tags: lua, roblox

i currently trying to do a teleport system in roblox studio, but you have to pay to teleport.
So this is the code i used, the problem is, as I sayed in the title, the code just stops and gives neither a feedback (print lines) or a error.

`

```
TeleportPart1.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local w = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
    if w then
        print("teleport_1")
        if w:FindFirstChild("CanTeleport") == true then
            print("Teleport_bought")
            w.CFrame = TeleportPart2.CFrame + Vector3.new(0, 5, 0)
            TeleportPart2.CanTouch = false
            wait(1)
            TeleportPart2.CanTouch = true
        elseif w:FindFirstChild("CanTeleport") == false then
            print("Teleport_prompt")
            local market = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
            market.PromptProductPurchase(w, 1348388842)
            if market.PromptPurchaseFinished then
                w.CFrame = TeleportPart2.CFrame + Vector3.new(0, 5, 0)
                TeleportPart2.CanTouch = false
                wait(1)
                TeleportPart2.CanTouch = true
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

`

I tried to debug but it didn't solve the problem. If i run the code and touch the teleporter it only prints "teleport_1" but not "Teleport_bought" or "Teleport_prompt". Idk what kind of an error this is i guess it has to do something with the FindFirstChild.

Comment: `FindFirstChild` returns either the Instance it finds or `nil`. It will never return `true` or `false`

Comment: But it does not neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `WaitForChild()` instead of `FindFirstChild()`. There really isn't a reason to use `FindFirstChild()` since `WaitForChild()` does the same thing but waits for the target if it has not found it.